# Как убрать фигурные скобки из ttk.combobox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Использую такой код для добавления в список столбцов из бд.

```py
cur.execute('SELECT id, name FROM clients')
self.e_client = ttk.Combobox(win, width=17, values=cur.fetchall())
```

Если в строке столбца больше одного слова(то есть есть пробелы), то ttk.Combobox добавляет фигурные скобки.

[image]

Как от них избавиться?

Comment: Куда добавляет фигурные скобки?

Comment: В сам выпадающий список. И при выборе в поле они тоже появляются

Comment: Добавьте скриншот хотя бы. Не понятно что за фигурные скобки.

Comment: Прошу прощения, в первый раз вопрос задаю) Добавил

Comment: А значения из самого столбца `name` не содержат фигурных скобок?

Comment: Нет, не содержат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `fetchall` возвращает список кортежей такого вида:

```
[(1, 'Иванов Иван Иванович'), (2, 'Петров Иван Сергеевич')]
```

В каждом кортеже набор значений, которые вы получаете с помощью `select`. Чтобы отображалось как вам нужно, а не как захочет combobox, перед вставкой в него нужно преобразовать эти данные в список строк. Например, можно сформировать список только имен:

```
e_client = ttk.Combobox(win, width=17, values=[row[1] for row in cur.fetchall()])
```

Либо сформировать строки в нужном вам виде, например с помощью `format`:

```
e_client = ttk.Combobox(win, width=17, values=["{} - {}".format(*row) for row in cur.fetchall()])
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это решило мою проблему)

Comment: Странно, как раз проверял на примере кортежей (число, строка) вывод, у меня всё в порядке вывелось.

Comment: @Jazzis, combobox не дал мне скриншот сделать, вот так отображается при вставке кортежей в listbox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss6y2.png